# How could I get [a,0,b,0,c,0] when I give [a,b,c]?

Tags: prolog

I've made this code:

```
ceros([A|B],[C|D]):-
C is [A,0],
ceros(B,D).
```

and when I try this consult:

```
?- ceros([a,b,c],X)
```

I'm supposed to get:
X=[a,0,b,0,c,0]

but I get an error:

```
Arithmetic: `[_2554,0]' is not a function
```

I've no idea why I'm getting this error so I'd be so grateful if someone can explain it for me. Thanks

Comment: So `is` and `=` are not the same thing in Prolog. `is/2` evaluates an arithmetic expression on the right-hand side to a value on the left-hand side. If you replaced `is` with `=`, you would have gotten `X=[[a,0],[b,0],[c,0]]`, assuming you added the missing base case `ceros([], []).`

Answer (score 1):

Got it

```
ceros([],[]).
ceros([A|B],[A,0|D]):-
ceros(B,D).
```